Vaildation of Data after uploadind CSV file in oracle Apex
I am uploading a CSV file then only do I want to parse data and apply validation on data. Display the error message which is giving an error. The data which is correct should be entered into the table. Display how many rows are inserted.
Tried using dynamic action. Please help me.

That is a very vague question ... Check out this blog on how to create a data loading page. .That should give you enough information to start with. If you get stuck on anything particular you can post a new question. Apex is a dev platform, functionality can be implemented in many ways. Please make your question as detailed so it can be reproduced by the members of the community.
